# Deploying django: "no module named.."

Tags: django, deployment, module, webfaction

Im trying to deploy my django proyect under a webfaction server. I have an app named "home".

**FACT A)** If i move my "home" folder to the same directory of manage.py and i set my setting.py like this, the app **works fine**.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'home'
)
```

**FACT B)** If i move my "home" folder to the apps directory, and set my settings.py like this, **i recive an error**  "No module named myproject.apps.home"

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'myroject.apps.home'
)
```

The thing is i want to set my "home" app under the apps folder. Where could be the problem? i've been trying to configurate httpd.conf in apache but i didn't succeed.

**This is my folder tree:**

```
myproject_name
  -apache2
  -bin
  -lib
  --myproject
    -manage.py
    --myproject
      -wsgi.py
      -urls.py
      -__init__.py
      -settings.py
      -apps
```

Django version: 1.4.2
python version: 2.7
mod_wsgi version: 3.4

Thanks for your time

Comment: The `home` and `apps` folders must have `__init__.py` file to be considerd as a package. Do you have it there?

Comment: To myself: "Of course i must have an __init__.py i just...*facepalm*"
That was the problem, thanks for answer so quickly.

Comment: glad it helped you. I have posted this as an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `home` and `apps` folders must have `__init__.py` file to be considerd as a package. Make sure you have it there.